# Javascript Validation (Input not showing after clicking Submit)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, submit, innerhtml

This is a simple code and I don't know where I went wrong.. Name validation works if no name is entered, but it doesn't show the result when a valid name is entered.

Here's my code:

I'm just new in html and javascript, hoping i'd get help from here. Thank you

```js
  function checkname(form) {
    var eobj = document.getElementById('MITname');
    var jname = form.Name.value;
    var error = false;

    eobj.innerHTML = '';

    if (jname == '') {
      error = "Name is required!";
      var error2 = error.fontcolor("red");

    }
    if (error) {
      if (hasFocus == false) {
        form.Name.focus();
        hasFocus = true;
      }
      eobj.innerHTML = error2;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function showinput() {
    document.getElementById('namedisplay').innerHTML = document.getElementById('MITname').value;
  }


  function validate() {
    hasFocus = false;
    var form = document.forms['form'];
    var ary = [checkname];
    var rtn = true;
    var z0 = 0;
    for (var z0 = 0; z0 < ary.length; z0++) {
      if (!ary[z0](form)) {
        rtn = false;
      }
    }
    return rtn;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" name="form" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Name:<font color="red">*</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="Name" /> <span id="MITname"> </span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showinput()" />
  <br/>
  <label>Your input:</label>
  <p><span id="namedisplay"></span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues here. (Also, welcome to Web Development!)

First, you never actually create the variable `hasFocus`. So you're never actually checking if it's true/false or not.

Second, where you create `error2` means that it will only be accessible within the `if()` block it was created in. So, in the following `if(error)` block when you try to access it, it will return `undefined`.

Third, when you create `error` you are setting the value to `false`, which indicates a Boolean type, but then later setting its value to a String, which is definitely not a Boolean.

Fourth, the line `var ary = [checkname];` is confusing to me. I get that you're trying to convert the name (from the input?) to an array, but that is not the way to do it. You can access each character of the name with `string.charAt(index)`, so creating an array isn't really necessary.

Fifth, your `validate()` function as a whole is **very** confusing. I haven't a clue what you're trying to do. It looks like your teaching source may have mislead you, or you weren't paying attention that closely.

I could go on, however those (among other) issues are really making it difficult to find exactly what is going wrong, without digging too much into it. I don't want to write this for you, and so my suggestion would be to start again, and maybe checkout some more tutorials, perhaps from a different source. (Different youtube channel, etc.)

Comment: I assume (assume) that the validate function should make an array of all forms then call `checkname` for each form...instead it iterates over a 1 variable array to call `checkname`

Comment: it's my first day in class and that's self taught.. i myself not sure what am i coding, but i'm aiming to make a javascript validation.. knowing that this code is horrible, that's a bit of a let down.. *sigh* thanks tho, i appreciate it.

Comment: @Geni-sama, don't feel bad, we all had to start somewhere. What I'd suggest doing is watching some "intro to Javascript" videos online, and looking at W3 Schools, as they have great stuff for beginners.

Comment: i have rewritten the code.. my only problem is the validation, if i input a blank name an error message would appear next to the Name's text box.. I'll post the code as an answer.. i hope you're still interested to help

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the validation. If I enter a blank name, an error message should appear next to the Name's text box indicating to enter a valid name.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JAVASCRIPT FORM VALIDATION</title>
 
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function showMessage()
  {
            var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
            displayname.innerHTML= Name;
   
   var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
   displayemail.innerHTML= Email;
   
   var Website = document.getElementById("Website").value;
   displaywebsite.innerHTML= Website;
   
   var Comment = document.getElementById("Comment").value;
   displaycomment.innerHTML= Comment;
   
   var nameerror='';
   var emailerror='';
   var websiteerror='';
   var commenterror='';
   
    if (displayname.innerHTML=='')
    {
    nameerror = 'Please enter a valid name';
    return false;
    }
    return true;
        }
    </script>
 
</head>

<body>

Name: <input type="text" id = "Name"> <span id = "nameerror"> </span>
<br></br>
Email: <input type="text" id = "Email">
<br></br>
Website: <input type="text" id = "Website">
<br></br>
Comnent: <textarea cols="35" rows="7" id="Comment"> </textarea>
<br></br>

<input type="submit" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />

   <p>Name: <span id = "displayname"></span> </p>
   <p>Email: <span id = "displayemail"></span> </p>
   <p>Website: <span id = "displaywebsite"></span> </p>
   <p>Comment: <span id = "displaycomment"></span> </p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" name="form" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Name:<font color="red">*</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="Name" /> <span id="MITname"> </span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showinput()" />
  <br/>
  <label>Your input:</label>
  <p><span id="namedisplay"></span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Just remove type='submit' in your code it will submit your page while click once you click submit the data's are change to POST , So use button as type